# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (j,s){return new b.fn.init(j,s)} has no method 'when'

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a .getJSON and .when function to use some data in a routes calculation.  Unfortunately, the console is giving me the above error.  Please take a look and see what could be going wrong?  Thank you! (I have checked and the .getJSON code is working fine, and spitting out the array I need.  I just need to retrieve it and put it into waypts).

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var waypts = [];
    var data = $.getJSON("/westcoast_map.php", { westcoast_id : $('.opener').data('westcoast_id')});

    $.when(data).then(function(theData){
                      waypts = theData[1];
                      });
```

Comment: Why not just `data.done(function(theData) { ... });`, and in what jQuery version is this? And you're setting the array equal to what looks like a string ?

Comment: using that method, it gives the error: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done' ;  using jquery 1.4.4.min.js; ajax 1.7.1 from google and 1.9 from asp

Comment: Why the hell would you use three jQuery versions. That pretty much explains it. Use only the latest.

Comment: the 1.7.1 and 1.9 are ajax though, separate thing no?

Comment: Nope, stick with 1.9 and remove the rest. Some older plugins might not work, but those are to old anyway, so remove those as well :) ...

Comment: now it's saying that jquery is not defined

Comment: maybe i should be clearer: one of them has the ending 1.7.1/jquery.min.js, one is 1.9/jquery.validate.js, and one is a physical file on my ftp that is jquery-1.4.4.min.js

Comment: .min.js just means it's minified (compressed in size, same file), and the validate file is a plugin. You should just download jQuery 1.9 or link to google's CDN and use **only one** jQuery file, not counting jQuery UI, plugins etc.

Comment: unless you cant (through legacy code, can't remove others, etc.), you should only load one version of jquery and use it throughout, preferabbly the latest.

Comment: loading more than one version of jQuery is likely main cause of problem. Especially since `$.when` didn't exist in 1.4

Answer (score -1):

please check whether you are using jQuery library < jQuery 1.5 
you must use > = jQuery 1.5 in order to use $.when